# Swift type checker rejects protocol that has a class requirement as a class type

Tags: swift, rx-swift

This is about an error encountered in https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxStarscream/pull/23.

I am trying to generalize a type, so I can mock the class it is based on. This means I want to switch from a concrete implementation to a protocol.

The original class looks like this:

```
open class WebSocket : NSObject, StreamDelegate, WebSocketClient, WSStreamDelegate { ... }
    ...
}
```

I want to replace this with this protocol, that `WebSocket` is already extending:

```
public protocol WebSocketClient : AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

This means I am replacing

```
public class RxWebSocketDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy<WebSocket, NSObjectProtocol>, ... {
    ...
}
```

with

```
public class RxWebSocketDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy<WebSocketClient, NSObjectProtocol>, ... {
    ...
}
```

All of this seems easy enough — `WebSocketClient` provides all the functionality that is needed here. Surprisingly, I am receiving the error message

> 'DelegateProxy' requires that 'WebSocketClient' be a class type

I am not sure what I am missing here and would appreciate pointers!

Comment: This looks like its due to [protocols not conforming to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878)

Comment: That is it — thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **@objc** like below:

```
@objc public protocol WebSocketClient : AnyObject {
    ---
}
```